# find and replace multiple files using a file as input to find and another to replace

Tags: linux, ssh, find, grep

I need to replace several chunks of text inside some php scripts...

i have:

```
find . -name 'products.php' -exec grep --silent 'TEXT_TO_FIND' {} \; -exec ls {} \; -exec sed -i 's/TEXT_TO_FIND/REPLACE_TEXT/g' {} \;
```

this work, but i have text of about 2 ou 3 lines..

so i remember to create a find.txt with my find text and another replace.txt with the replacement text..

my question is.. how can i use this files as inputs in the above command..

something like:

```
find . -name 'products.php' -exec grep --silent `cat find.txt` ...
```

Best regards Bruno

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i can't come to a specific command, but maybe `xargs` utility will come in handy. It executes lines of the text file or `stdin` as commands. For example, following command prints file information about all files in current directory:

```
/bin$ ls | xargs file
bash:             ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x6c2d022503edd4e409032f33bffbcb66d2546ea5, stripped
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question, but if you mean you want to find/change several items in a single command, maybe this answers your needs:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -l -E 'finditem1|finditem2|finditem3' {} \; -exec sed -i -e "s/finditem1/replitem1/" -e "s/finditem2/replitem2/" -e "s/finditem3/replitem2/" {} \;
```

Also, both grep and sed accept files as inputs, but you'll have to create 2 distinct files for grep matches and sed commands. 
Alternatives may exist also with awk or perl.